# Laravel retrieve image from storage and failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, image, laravel-5.4

I am having problems with Laravel retrieving images and being able to use those images in my controller.

I first check to make sure the image exists which returns true

```
var_dump(storage::disk('local')->exists('image.png'))
```

If i do this

```
$file = Storage::disk('local')->get('image.png');
var_dump(pathinfo($file));
```

i get this output

```
array(2) {
  ["basename"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["filename"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Just var_dump()ing the `$file` gives me an empty string

If i do this

```
$file = Storage::disk('local')->url('image.png');
var_dump(pathinfo($file));
```

i get

```
array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
  string(8) "/storage"
  ["basename"]=>
  string(9) "image.png"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "png"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(5) "image"
}
```

I don't want to know the properties, I need to be able use that actual stored image and upload it to another API.

If I try and do

```
echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
```

i get this in the browser source but can't see any image

```
<img src="/storage/image.png">
```

The API i'm using to upload the image returns this

```
mime_content_type(/storage/image.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I'm convinced once I can get the actual image, the rest of it will work

**EDIT:**

I've run this command `php artisan storage:link`

If i use `$file = public_path('uploads/image.png');` and copy the file into the public folder (not storage/app/public), I am able to use the image how I want

This is not ideal as I don't want the images to be publicly accessible. I need to be able to access the image from the storage folder.

If I run `$file = Storage::disk('public')->get('image.jpg');` I get `mime_content_type(): Invalid path`

I'm at wits end trying to send a path to the image to the API I need to use. All it needs is `/the/path/to/the/image`

Other code i've tried results in a 403 when trying to get the image

Answer (score 0):

The `/storage` folder outside the public directory, which is the web server's document / web root. The public are no access to the `/storage` folder. You should make a response to output the image content.

```
$path = storage_path() . "/app/image.png";
$file = File::get($path);
$type = File::mimeType($path);
$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);
return $response;
```

Comment: I now get `File does not exist at path /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/storage/image.jpg`

Comment: could be stored in app folder, `$path = storage_path() . "/app/image.png";` check this out: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-local-driver

Comment: What about using symbolic link? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration